# About the semantically related words Google's algorithm uses in mixed language websites

Tags: internationalization, seo

Because I'm Latin, sometimes I use a word in English while talking in Spanish.

In a website, for example, I could be interested in ranking for a word as “promoter” inside a page in Spanish, because that is how my public understands that concept.  Does the latent semantic indexing (LSI) (or whatever Google uses for semantic relation) fail to relate “promoter” with the content (because there are not related words in English) and then could that prevent my site from ranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix two languages within a single page.  Google uses the words that you use to determine which language you are writing in.  Then it uses your site in the search engine result pages (SERPs) only for users who speak that language.    When you mix languages, it confuses Google in this regard.  [Google asks that you not mix languages in a single page](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-start-multilingual-site.html).

> Avoid mixing languages on each page, as this may confuse Googlebot as well as your users. Keep navigation and content in the same language on each page.

In the case of a word here and a word there that your users are likely to understand, it shouldn't confuse Googlebot too much.   [Here is a report from a blogger who is unhappy with that policy from Google and ranks fine using an occasional multilingual word or phrase](http://climbtothestars.org/archives/2008/08/09/google-dont-mix-languages-on-the-same-page/):

> I’m really disappointed to see this kind of advice handed out. Yes, it confuses Googlebot, but only because it doesn't (I guess?) take into account lang=”xx” attributes. (Yeah, nobody uses them, but that’s because nobody parses them.)
>
> But users? Most people are not pure monolinguals. We need ways to make linguistic barriers online weaker, and not stronger.
>
> I've been mixing languages on Climb to the Stars for eight years now, and it hasn't prevented my readers or my Page Rank from being happy.

I see that you also [asked this question in the Google Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/ycUGhk9asBA/INTxWjFJwrUJ) where Google's John Mueller says:

> Doing that is fine and not something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, i think like that blogguer. There should be something I could do because this case isn't weird, there many words in many languajes that are taken from another languaje.

Comment: Ah, like im a new, why does my post had been migrated to webmaster...?

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions that can be answered with code and your question would be considered off topic and closed there.  Your question is a much better fit here and can stay open.  I asked that it be moved when I answered it.

Comment: Oh thanks! I dindnt know, and like i have seen SEO posts in SO...

Comment: I watch the SEO tag on StackOverflow and about half the post would be better here.   Some are about url structure or something like that that can be answered with how to code it.   I ask the moderators to move the other off topic ones. Unfortunately, about half get closed before they are moved.  I've brought it up on meta and you can comment there if you want to continue this discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169177/210998